# Will dishwasher be OK for a few days with broken retaining tab at the bottom of the overflow float assembly?

Tags: dishwasher

I'm planning to replace the float assembly on my Whirlpool dishwasher because I thought it was a little sticky and I'm seeing intermittent leaks. I already ordered a [replacement](https://www.partsips.com/float-asm-part-wpw10077871) that will arrive next week. But when removing the old one to test it, I accidentally pulled it out hard enough to break off the little tab on the bottom that normally prevents it from being pulled out by idiots like me. :-)

When I put the old float back in and move it up and down, I can hear the switch activating. So I'm not worried about that. But without the little retaining tab, during the wash cycle will the float get pushed out of its housing and start flying around the inside of the dishwasher?  Or is it likely to be kept in place because the water inside doesn't rise high enough?  I know I can run the dishwasher to find out, but before I do that (and potentially break something and/or leak all over the floor) I was wondering if anyone knows what will happen.

Here's what the part looks like. The little wider piece at the bottom end is what I broke off.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you get some dishwashing soap and some dish towels, that will work until you get it fixed

Comment: yeah.it will be absolutely fine if you do not use it,  this is not life-support equipment.

Comment: Actually, the dishwasher should be fine to use, as long as the broken-off tab does  not block the fill shut-off switch from opening. If you can, fish out the tab with a sewing needle (*without* damaging the switch!). Some washers have that float completely free to come off, so the tab is not essential.